# Android Studio Parse Server not working

Tags: java, android, sdk, parse-server

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.karanvir.myapplication5">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My problem is that my parse server wont get any information from my app. I have included error logs, starter class, and main class. My parse server shows no information being passed to it.

**different because I have not been able to find a proper answer**

```js
07-13 11:47:23.618 16945-16945/com.karanvir.myapplication5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.karanvir.myapplication5, PID: 16945
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.karanvir.myapplication5/com.karanvir.myapplication5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:499)
                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseCorePlugins.getLocalIdManager(ParseCorePlugins.java:328)
                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseObject.getLocalIdManager(ParseObject.java:87)
                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseObject.getOrCreateLocalId(ParseObject.java:1310)
                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1719)
                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1673)
                                                                                 at com.karanvir.myapplication5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

```css
package com.karanvir.myapplication5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);


        ParseObject object= new ParseObject("example");
                object.put("my number","123");
        object.put("my string","karn");
        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                if(e==null){
                    Log.i("hello","anything");
                } else {
                    Log.i("random","morerandom");
                }

            }
        });
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

```html
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.karanvir.myapplication5;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("77")
            .clientKey( "32")
            .server( "harse/")
            .build()
    );
/*
    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
    object.put("myNumber", "123");
    object.put("myString", "rob");

    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException ex) {
        if (ex == null) {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
        }
      }
    });


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
*/
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Do not do `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this)` in Activity 2) `.server( "harse/")` seems strange, should be a url or ip, usually ending with `/parse` if I remember correctly

Comment: yeah i just changed it up so no one can see my stuff

Comment: Did you add permissions to your manifest? Seems Parse cannot write to sd

Comment: yes I did, please look now. i added the manifest

Comment: now with everything layed out, what do you guys think

Comment: Think it needs write permission, not sure though. Otherwise try excluding the enabling of local datastore

Comment: Think maybe you haven't added StarterApplication to your manifest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685242

Comment: thanks for the link bro, but that question is still unsolved . so idk what to do anymore

Comment: Alright but have you tried adding <application android:name=".StarterApplication"...? :)

Comment: nooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: what is thatttt

Comment: In the manifest, it tells android to use your own Application object. That what was I tried to show with the link (the answer with 6 up votes)

Comment: Otherwise the initialization of Parse in onCreate is never invoked

Comment: thats my error nitialization of Parse in onCreate is never invoked. when i read my error logs. how do i fix this

Comment: Add ` android:name=".StarterApplication".` in application tag in manifest as described in the answer I linked